# Batch Update with Dynamic IDs Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to batch update a table by an ID

My **controller:**

```
if(customCompute($this->data['student'])) {
                            $studentextendID = $this->data['student']->studentextendID;
                            $this->data['students'] = $this->studentextend_m->get_studentextend(array('studentextendID' => $studentextendID));
                            } else {
                                $this->data['students'] = [];
                        }
        

                        $post = $this->input->post();
                        for($i=0; $i < count($post['subject']); $i++) {
                            $studentExtendArray[] = array(
                                'studentextendID' => $studentextendID,
                                'studentID' => $studentID,
                                'subject' => $post['subject'][$i],
                                'subjectng' => $post['subjectng'][$i],
                                'subjectlg' => $post['subjectlg'][$i],
                                'subjectcre' => $post['subjectcre'][$i],
    
    
                            );
                        $this->db->update_batch('studentextend', $studentExtendArray, 'studentextendID');

                        }
```

My **Model**

```
 function get_studentextend($array=NULL, $signal=FALSE) {
    $query = parent::get($array, $signal);
    return $query;
}
```

**Array Output:**

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [studentextendID] => 143
        [studentID] => 97
        [subject] => 
        [subjectng] => 5235
        [subjectlg] => 5231
        [subjectcre] => 523155
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [studentextendID] => 143
        [studentID] => 97
        [subject] => 
        [subjectng] => 2
        [subjectlg] => 99
        [subjectcre] => 3
    ) )
```

As you can see, **'studentextendID'** is duplicated on both arrays, when it should be dynamically obtained, for example: 143 and 144, because there are two rows in the table with the same **'studentID'**

Comment: We probably need to saw your full function instead of the if part, from where you get the var `$studentID` ?  Also you force the `studentExtendID` with the line : 
`$studentextendID = $this->data['student']->studentextendID; `

Comment: There's no use to see the studentID, cause it's already working fine, and obtaining the studentid from the table. Also, I don't really get what you mean by forcing the studentextendID?

Comment: What version of Codeigniter are you using? You seem to be misusing the Stack Overflow question tags (*"codeigniter-3" & "codeigniter-4"*).

Comment: My bad, I'm using CI 3

Answer (score 0):

You can try with change in model

```
public function update_batchs($table, $data)
{
    if ($data) {
        return $this->db->update_batch($table, $data, 'studentextendID');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried it but didn't work.. It was already updating, but it only updates one row, as it only gets one studentextendID,

Comment: you can try also do with foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

You are not pass the $studentextendID in for loop.You need to pass this in for loop.

```
$studentextendID = $this->data['student']->studentextendID;
```

And also please verify $this->data['student'].